# Duality of projective and injective objects

Tags: category-theory

It is well known that in an arbitrary category the notion of injective and projective objects are dual. My question is: what is a precise, mathematical formulation of this duality?

Comment: What's more to give than: injective in $C$ iff projective in $C^{op}$?

Comment: @user10354138 I mean that's the obvious one, but I was wondering if there was a way to spell it out, or perhaps a more intuitive way of stating this?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with the reformulation "it's the exact same definition but with the arrows reversed" ?

Comment: @gen it's not clear what "spelling [this] out" would consist of, and in the comments you're requesting intuition while in the original post you're requesting precision. It would help to be more specific about what you find unsatisfying about the definition of "dual".

Comment: @KevinCarlson, I accept as an answer that there is no other /insightful/ way of stating this duality. In category theory you can often define notions in many equivalent ways, for example you can define products as limits or just explicitly via morphisms and universality. I was just wondering if there's a similar, more explicit way of stating this duality of injective & projective objects.